# Salesforce List with Multiple Filters

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object called Registrations. The Registration tab shows registrations made by currently logged in user. So it has **My Registrations** in View dropdown. How can I create additional dropdowns in addition to View dropdown:-

1) Dropdown to select event Name.
2) Calendar field(icon) to display a calendar.

Once user sets the criteria and clicks on Go the results should be displayed after applying all the criteria.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this out of the box. In order to achieve this you would have to create a custom VF page and replace the core "List" view for the Registrations object with the VF page.

The problem with this approach is that you loose the functionality of List Views. You will have to code it all in the VF page controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks slashApex. Creating a custom Visualforce page worked for me.